# Strangely low framerate in Shadow Fight 2 for Windows 8

Tags: windows-10, framerate, shadow-fight-2

I've been playing Shadow Fight 2 (Windows Store version) for about 2 months now, and recently a friend of mine decided to play the iOS version. The iOS version appears to have a *much* better framerate!

**Despite my "slower" Windows version:**

- The timer still kept time accurately (1s in-game = 1s realtime)
- Gameplay was still acceptable
- Background particles moved at the same speed

**What I've tried:**

- Lowering graphics quality (framerate actually dropped)
- Reinstalling
- Going offline/online (only reduced loading time)

**Computer specs:**

- Windows 10 Pro
- Intel 6th-gen i5 core
- 4GB RAM

**Special notice:** Using a temperature-monitoring program, it appears that Shadow Fight 2 runs smoother  (comparable to the framerate of the iOS version) when my computer is above 38°C.

---

What is the reason behind this?  Is there anything I can do to improve the framerate of the game?

Comment: Do you meet the system requirements for the game?

Comment: According to the site, it is recommended to use a Windows phone...  But other than that, I meet the system requirements.

Comment: So you're not even playing it on the platform it's meant for?  Then the fact that you got it running at all should be good. We can't really support a game running on a system it's not meant for; there are way too many variables in play to be able to help.

Comment: Since you've not mentioned your specs, nor how you're running a mobile game on a PC, I am voting to close this as unclear.  We *might* be able to help, but we'll need a whole lot more info before we can.

Comment: @Frank I'm not sure if you know this, but apps for the Windows phone can be played on the PC, due to the availability of the Windows App Store that is cross-compatible with both mobile and PC. For example, Tiny Towers is available both on the Windows 8.1 PC as well as 8.1 Mobile

Comment: @hotlinecalifornia If that's the version being run, that would take care of that aspect.  I was not aware of that, actually.  I'm still not sure how that translates mobile to PC requirements, though; they run a similiar OS, but I don't believe the system requirements *can* be the same.  The PC Windows 8 OS is going to be *much* beefier than the mobile one, and will neccesitate a much better computer to run.

Comment: @Frank I've included my computer specs in the question now.  I'm _pretty sure_ my computer can handle the game...

Answer (score 3):

I once worked porting a game from iOS to Windows 8.1 app. The process was quite cumbersome to say the least. The problem with 8.1 apps is that they sometimes require an extra layer of processing to handle the Windows OS calls. As previous Windows products, it doesn't like following standards so much. It prefers to establish its own.

Even after the porting, the game didn't work as well as in iOS, we spent some time fixing things that got broken out of nowhere during the transformation, and in the end the game worked well, but nos as flawlessly as in the iOS version.

So I'd say that if the game was not originally developed as a Windows 8.1 app, then such game is likely to have porting issues, as developing for the other platforms is quite different than developing to Windows 8.1. Keep in mind also that this will affect the use of your computer resources by the game, as, if it is a port, the game will be designed to work with low resources and not with a full fledged PC. That's one of the cons of the 8.1 app portability. You can only avoid the previous issues when building the game in question from scratch with the Windows 8.1 environment as a target.